# Create react app script run dev webserver error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

error log:

> events.js:112
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: watch /home/cchen/My/gallering/frontend/public EMFILE
>       at _errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
>       at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1409:19)
>       at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1435:11)
>       at createFsWatchInstance (/home/cchen/My/gallering/frontend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
>       at setFsWatchListener (/home/cchen/My/gallering/frontend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
>       at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/cchen/My/gallering/frontend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
>       at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/cchen/My/gallering/frontend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:407:19)
>       at FSWatcher. (/home/cchen/My/gallering/frontend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:455:19)
>       at FSWatcher. (/home/cchen/My/gallering/frontend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:460:16)
>       at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:171:5) error Command failed with exit code 1.

It looks like a watchman failed at first.
I reinstall watchman but still got the same error.

Comment: Yes! It's because the open file limit!. Thanks man. I will close this.